# trigger mouseleave but not if over a specific element

Tags: jquery

I have an element appear / disappear depending on whether or not the cursor is over a specific element.

But I don't want it to disappear if the cursor is over the element which appear/disappears.

So i have this:

```
$('.main-menu ul li.last').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.books-online-shop-submenu').slideDown();
});

$('.main-menu ul li.last, .books-online-shop-submenu').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.books-online-shop-submenu').slideUp();
});
```

But I don't want `.books-online-shop-submenu` to slideUp if the cursor is over IT.

I tried the following as per another answer I found on SO, but it does not work:

```
$('.main-menu ul li.last').not('.books-online-shop-submenu').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.books-online-shop-submenu').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LJnQb/2/

Comment: @Arun That does it! Can you post it as your answer so I can accept? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $target = $('.books-online-shop-submenu'),
        timer;
    $('.main-menu ul li.last').hover(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $target.stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    }, function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }, 200);
    });

    $target.hover(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, function () {
        $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LJnQb/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**:

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('.books-online-shop-submenu').mouseenter(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').mouseover(function() {
    $('selector').slideDown();
});

$('selector').mouseout(function() {
    $('selector').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
var inBookSubMenu = false;
$('.books-online-shop-submenu').mouseenter(function() {
    inBookSubMenu = true;
}).mouseleave(function() {
    inBookSubMenu = false;
});

$('.main-menu ul li.last').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.books-online-shop-submenu').slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    if (!inBookSubMenu) {
      $('.books-online-shop-submenu').slideUp();
    }
});
```